# Google API Data Modelling

Tags: google-api, data-modeling, google-api-python-client

Google currently has a discovery URL for each of their API. The document is in json format and contains all of the required information to consume the API. For example, the following is for the Forms API.

https://forms.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest

There's a python client that helps with consuming the API. However, it does not provide models with Intellisense and I have to construct the request resource as a dictionary. I haven't found any documentation about how the discovery document can be used in creating data models. What I would like to do is to create python models (classes with properties and methods) for the schema's section in the document

I have tried **[datamodel-code-generator](https://github.com/koxudaxi/datamodel-code-generator) **using the openapi parameter option. I have also tried to separate the schemas and process them as such but none actually produced usable classes. I have also tried a couple of tools from https://openapi.tools/#converters but no luck.

Using dictionary format for an API is against OOP principles. Any pointers to how to model Google API resources would be really appreciated.